# Recommend apps to simulate multiple BLE Beacons at once from one device?

Tags: location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I need to try and replicate multiple BLE beacons from 1 device, either iOS or Android or a Windows Laptop/PC, to assist with some testing.

All the apps I can find only allow 1 beacon to be broadcast at any one time

Ive tried many apps from the Appstore and Google Play store

Android

BeaconSimulator Agile4
Beacon Scope
BLE Scanner

iOS
my BLE Simulator
My Beacon Tester
Beacon Walker

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nevertheless, your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow.
_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: I think you can re-word this question to be on-topic. Simply ask if it is possible for an app to transmit more than one beacon at a time, noting that when you experiment with different apps this doesn't work.